# mvn jetty:run-forked inside a docker container?

Tags: shell, docker, jvm-arguments, maven-jetty-plugin, sigterm

I have an application that uses the jetty maven plugin ["run-forked" goal](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.4.x/jetty-maven-plugin.html#jetty-run-forked-goal) that I need to dockerize.  What happens is that maven starts, the container exists only for about 10 seconds and then dies when maven exits after it forks the child JVM process.

I have investigated many options.  One option that I thought might work is to set "waitForChild" to true and then 
do something like this:

```
ENTRYPOINT [ "/entrypoint.sh" ]
CMD [ "jetty:run-forked > /tmp/log 2>&1" ]
```

But, though this keeps maven running, the image does not build, because [Docker waits for a SIGTERM](http://veithen.github.io/2014/11/16/sigterm-propagation.html).

If you are wondering why I need to use jetty:run-forked, it is because the code requires a [static linked library that needs a JVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39842117/load-statically-compiled-library-in-java).

I am ready to throw in the towel, because this seems impossible ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure about your java set up, but a neat trick that works is something like this:

In your dockerfile, add a custom script like so:

```
COPY myscript.sh /bin/myscript.sh # Remember to make this executable!
```

then edit your ENTRYPOINT to reflect that:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/myscript.sh"]
```

Your `myscript.sh` could look a little something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Run Java/mvn commands here
...
jetty:run-forked > /tmp/log 2>&1

# Throw in a shell command that simply executes forever
tail -f /dev/null
```

This will ensure your container keeps running even after your jetty/mvn stuff spawns another process and quits, because it is no longer PID 1 within the container, the `myscript.sh` shell script is. This shell script continues to run forever because of the `tail -f`.

Comment: It works!  Thank you. Definitely a neat trick, and more than that, it is clear and simple.